# how to install lex and yacc in fedora?

Tags: fedora

I don't know how to install the `lex` and `yacc` in the fedora 24. I installed it in the ubuntu 16. Using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install bison
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there any reason why

```
dnf install flex-devel bison-devel
```

would not do the job?

Comment: I installed the lex and yacc using;1)yum install flex.2)yum install bison. But when i'm executing the lex program ,its displaying the error like; /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. Would you help me to resolve this.

Comment: @NikhilJadhav That sounds like a new question — please ask it separately.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for those who encountered the below error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

OR

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

step 1:

```
dnf install flex bison
```

step 2:

```
dnf install flex-devel bison-devel
```

then run it. I had the same issue, installing flex-devel solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer didn't do the job, but this did:

`sudo dnf install flex-devel bison-devel byacc`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1459817/how-to-get-the-package-name-of-a-non-built-in-command